# Is it bad to return a server error if user submits content they are not authorized too?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have a app where users can sign in with Twitter, Google and local. (I'm using passportjs)

If the users are signed in with Twitter or google I don't want to display options such as change email password etc.

To solve this in handlebars I check if a Twitter Id or google Id exist, if they do I hide the buttons to change email & password and instead display a message saying they cant change the email.

Now the problem is that if the user knows the route to the password change page (which isn't hard to figure out) they can still access the change password page. If they try to "change" their password they get a 500 response.

Is this a bad way to handle this specific situation? Does this open up other risks I'm not aware of?

Note: this is an expressjs app with handlebars template engine and passportjs.

Thanks.

Comment: Typically you would respond with something in the `400-499` range

Comment: For when I try to load the password change page or when I submit it?

Comment: Why would you think it would it be bad to throw an error for updating something they are not allowed too?

Comment: @Nick When they try to submit a new password, definitely a 400. When they just load the page - depends on how much serverside logic you have and whether you really care about this messing anything up. If you're just serving a static page with a form - nothing wrong with sending them the client the requested content, even if it's useless to them. If you're generating the content dynamically, or maybe even storing session state or create xsrf tokens, you might fail already there.

Comment: @epascarello no I'm saying should I give an error when they try to load the page or when they submit the password

Comment: @Bergi thanks, thats what I needed

Comment: You should do both... Always protect the api endpoints with validation.

Comment: @epascarello as someone said above why though if it's a static form which it is. Sorry if I sound like an idiot I'm new to expressjs and web security in general.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach what you are looking for would be to implement some middleware to prevent unauthorized users to upload content in the first place.

You can then throw errors from the controller just in case your middleware has some sort of leak.

Try something like (pseudocode):

```
(req, res, next)=>{
    if ("User is authenticated"){
        next()
    }
    res.redirect("Login page")
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. So I have 3 sign in methods, twitter, google and local. I only want the change email to show for people who are signed in locally. This is the middleware I made: `ensureLocal: function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.twitterId || req.body.googleId) {
      console.log('worked????');
      res.redirect('/profile');
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  },` Although it doesn't work. Is there a problem i'm not seeing